# Number of undos? One undo - Many undos?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, irregular-plurals

I'm creating an Andriod app/game. There you do moves and I'm counting the number of moves that's done. Then it is also possible to undo one or many moves.

What would you call it when counting the number of times you do undo?
E.g. "Number of **undos**"?

I'm not sure what the correct wording would be, but is it called:
"**One undo, many undos**"? Or how do you spell it?

I tried to google it but didn't find anything more than "undoes", but that doesn't mean the same I think.

I would like to type something like "Number of **undos**", but it doesn't look right to me!

Comment: Its a noun - the fact that it not currently very common makes no difference, The plural is **undos** - as you point out - "undoes" already exists in another meaning. --Also note that the "o" in "undo" does not resemble "hero" in pronunciation. Compare the awkward, yet correct "thes" as the plural of the noun "the"

Comment: Wiktionary is ever more reliable, and lists more words than any other English dictionary, often picking up on new usages before competitors. It gives **undos** as the sole plural.

Comment: A quick search of major dictionaries suggests that undo as a noun has not yet reached them. But undo as a noun in computation and the running of programmes is common. Undo singular, undos plural are justifiable. As a question involving a neologism, this should be left open for more informed answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're using "undo" as a noun. That's not necessarily wrong, especially in a computing context; the definitions that Google supplies when you search "define undo," which use Oxford dictionaries, mention that noun usage (and label it "computing"). But it's a relatively recent usage; more established and formal definitions only treat it as a verb.

When "verbing nouns" it's hard to ask what the "right" spelling of the plural is. But we can look to the conventions that typically govern the formation of plural nouns. The general rule is, for words that end in "o", to add -*es*:

- *hero* -> *heroes*
- *potato* -> *potatoes* (to Dan Quayle's downfall)

*But* there's a complication, because *undoes* already exists as a conjugation of the verb *undo*. I would argue that the confusion it raises is reason enough to simply add an -*s*. After all, there are plenty of exception words that simply add -*s* (most of them imported from other languages): *zeros*, *pianos*, *Fritos*.

Comment: Quayle's mistake was in instructing a child to add an *e* to the end of the singular *potato*.

Comment: @Robusto Yes, that's what I'm referring to. And ever since then I've had a hypercorrective, subconscious reflex to ask myself each time "Wait, was it that the plural should be *potatos*?"

Comment: I have a game that counts “undos.”

Comment: We also have "dos" as in ["dos and don'ts"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dos-and-donts"), so "undos" can be thought of as adding a prefix to that precedent

Comment: wiktionary also endorses "undos" as the plural (it also marks the noun sense as "computing")

Comment: I vote we make it irregular, to overcomplicate for humorous effect. und**ies**.

Comment: *Hero* and *potato* end in a different sound to *undo,* so that could licence a different pluralisation.

Comment: This is nouning a verb. // Wiktionary is a better authority than none.

Comment: @ChrisH I'd probably spell "dos" "do's" tbh, by analogy to the common use of an apostrophe for plurals of acronyms. I know it's not normative in formal communication, but it makes interpreting the pronunciation more intuitive ("dos" could reasonably be pronounced as "doze", "doss", or "dozz" in addition to the intended pronunciation)

Comment: @Tristan I've seen that done, but (thank goodness) it's not supported by major dictionaries.  Spelling is a rubbish clue to pronunciation anyway, and the use of apostrophes in plurals of acronyms (or more often initialisms) is itself not universally accepted.  In some contexts I might be tempted to read *dos* as in Spanish  for *two*, or as in French for *back*, but that wouldn't be an issue with "undos"

Comment: @Tristan "Today we'll cover the dos and don'ts of counting in English, as well as the dos and tres of counting in Spanish."

Comment: @R.M. Not to mention the DOS and Windows... and DoS attacks... (But, though I've been silent so far, no, I don't see using apostrophes for plurals as a step forward.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best would be to use [parenthetical plurals](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2015/04/parenthetical-plurals.html), i.e. "Undo(s)"

Comment: That could help, but it really ought to be limited to situations that can't be nailed down to singular or plural. In software engineering, a rookie mistake is "Balance: 1 **dollars**," but "Balance: 2 dollar(s)" is not a great improvement if one is able to alter the text programmatically.

Comment: In other words, an appropriate time for parenthetical plurals is when we're discussing a context so abstract that singular/plural can't be assumed: "Museum members with the basic membership may bring 1 visitor per visit; premium members may bring 2. Members must sign their visitor(s) in."

Comment: @AndyBonner we are after all discussing English here, but if there's any thought of internationalising the app, this gets much harder. In English you need short list of true exceptions (*alumnus*->*alumni*, *goose*->*geese*) a list that take *--es* (potato) and the normal case of *--s*.  "Balance: $1" and "number of undos: 1" work around this

Comment: ... or 'Undo(es)' as in 'hero(es)'?  This does not address the basic question.

Comment: @ChrisH Actually my first attempt at an example for the poor programming was "You have 1 life(s)," before realizing that that has bigger issues...

Comment: There are multiple plausible ways to form the plural of "undo," but "undo(s)" is not one of them.